# Liquid layout with textbox CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem in which a the post button for a text box is being pushed down when the screen is resized as demonstrated in the pictures:

From this:
[image]

To this:

[image]

The width of the text box is 83% and the width of the post button is 14% which adds up to 97%. I thought with a liquid layout, as long as the width percentages do not go over 100%, you are fine? Can someone explain why this is happening as I cant seem to figure it!

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="pageWrapper">
    <div class="newsfeedPostForm">
        <form action="public_posts.php" method="POST">
            <textarea id="newsfeedPost" name="post" rows="5" cols="90"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="send" class="postFormSubmit" value="Post">
        </form>
    </div>
<div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#pageWrapper {
width: 56%;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
border-left: 1px solid #cad3dc;
border-right: 1px solid #cad3dc;
}

.newsfeedPostForm {
width: 71%;
height: 77px;
background-color: #e5e6e7;
padding: 5px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}

#newsfeedPost {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 83%;
max-height: 66px;
margin-top: 4px;
margin-left: 4px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.postFormSubmit {
background-color: #DCE5EE; 
position:relative;
float: right; 
width: 14%;
height:69px;  
margin-right: 4px;
}
```

Comment: No, you are not fine as long as the total is under 100%, because widths do not take the margins/padding/borders of itself and the containing elements into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use box-sizing: border-box on .newsfeedPostForm. That should solve your problem.

```
.newsfeedPostForm {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    .....
}
```

You can read [here](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) for more information on box-sizing and the problem it solves.

Comment: Thank you sir, I was unaware of this property! Excellent article!

Comment: No problem at all!! And please don't call me sir, makes me sound very old!! :-))